# zkSNARK and definition of Quadratic Span Program

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, circuit

In [zkSNARKs in a Nutshell](http://chriseth.github.io/notes/articles/zksnarks/zksnarks.pdf), page 12, what exactly are $I_{free}$ and $V_{free}$? Why do we have $V_{free}$ but not $W_{free}$?

Comment: That first question is fine, but the second one is asking for references and the third one is too broad, which are both reasons for us to close the question. The third question could be a separate question in which you mention what you don't understand about Quadratic Arithmetic Programs: the more precise your question the better (i.e. ask about a part of the explanation that you do not understand). Please adjust your question!